# Google Appengine large amount of index data (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, bigtable

We've just outgrown our free data usage quota in AppEngine which is great but looking at our data breakup, only 200M of the 1G is actual data / meta-data (still can't believe they pin you for that one) and the rest I assume is indexes from reading the help forums. Does anyone know if this is normal and if not are there any good tips to reduce the size of the indexed data?

Cheers,
Richard

Comment: Who would you have Google charge to store the indexes, instead?

Comment: Happy to have the charges for indexed data just wandering if I've made some poor design decisions. With our 1GB of used data, only 200MB is actual data (not indexes) and of that 53% is meta data - it  seems like I must be doing something wrong if only 10% of our data usage is actual data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you are storing in it. We've got 32GB of String/Integer/Text data, 181GB of indexes/meta-data and 812GB of blobs (we are storing a lot of small images). So it really depends on your queries and settings.

You can run

```
   appcfg.py vacuum_indexes .
```

to vacum indexes (remove unused stuff).

GAE automatically creates simple indexes for all properties, but you can disable them by adding

```
    indexed=False
```

on the property. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html